# HTML Website Failing to Switch Between Tabs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm very new to the whole web development scene, so what I'm asking may be blisteringly obvious. For an english assessment, I have to create and host a webpage, of a particular text (in my case, I've chosen the Hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy). Now in the assessment, it is outlined that we are allowed to use code from other websites as a template for our own website, so I do stress, this is not my code. I got the code from 'http://dayzepoch.com/'. So far, I have placeholder information, and customised the webpage, to my needs. Currently, the webpage is hosted at 'http://hiimstring3.hpage.com/' on 'hPage'. Now, my page loads just fine, but when I click on one of the links, it stays on that page for a few seconds, but then loads the original DayZ Epoch website. I believe this is something to do with the below section of code under body:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a href="http://dayzepoch.com/#home"> Home </a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="http://dayzepoch.com/#install" data-toggle="tab"> Characters </a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="http://dayzepoch.com/#servers" data-toggle="tab"> Places </a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="http://dayzepoch.com/#community_servers" data-toggle="tab"> Ships </a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="http://dayzepoch.com/#teamspeak" data-toggle="tab"> About </a></li>     
</ul>
```

Now, I don't know how to change this, so that my website has the same functionality as the original website, but using my url, instead of these ones. If someone could help me out, then I would really appreciate it.

-Michael

Comment: Are you using jquery ui tabs - have a look at http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: `href="http://dayzepoch.com/#home"` ? Shouldn't the href be pointing to your own site? `href="http://hiimstring3.hpage.com/#home"` ?

Comment: @abhitalks I have tried that, however, to no avail, all it does when I load it, is it goes to the active tab, and when I click on another one, it doesn't load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are  http://jqueryui.com/tabs/ then the href you not be including the url of another website.

it should be of the format

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home"> Home </a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#install" data-toggle="tab"> Characters </a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#servers" data-toggle="tab"> Places </a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#community_servers" data-toggle="tab"> Ships </a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#teamspeak" data-toggle="tab"> About </a></li>     
</ul>
```

Comment: I tried that, and it didn't work. I think I am using CSS to provide the UI for my tabs, when I try your method, it removes that UI and lists them vertically.